# How can boost::serialization be used with std::unique_ptr from C++

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

I am trying to use boost::serialization library to serialize a class (the class A in following code) which is including a std::unique_ptr member.

Environment:

OS: Windows 10 1909

IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.4

Library: boost-serialization 1.72.0 (installed with [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) tool)

```cpp
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
    }

    A(int input_size, int input_value)                  //  Constructor
    {
        this->data = std::make_unique<int[]>(input_size);
        this->size = input_size;
        for (int loop_number = 0; loop_number < size; loop_number++) {
            data[loop_number] = input_value;
        }
    }

    std::unique_ptr<int[]> get_data()
    {
        //  deep copy
        auto return_data = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);
        for (int loop_number = 0; loop_number < size; loop_number++) {
            return_data[loop_number] = data[loop_number];
        }
        return return_data;
    }
    int get_size()
    {
        return this->size;
    }
    ~A()
    {
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> data;
    int size;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar& data;
        ar& size;
    }
};


int main()
{
    // create and open a character archive for output
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");

    // create class instance
    const A a_object(10, 5);

    // save data to archive
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        // write class instance to archive
        oa << a_object;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }

    // ... some time later restore the class instance to its orginal state
    A load_from_file;
    {
        // create and open an archive for input
        std::ifstream ifs("filename");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        // read class state from archive
        ia >> load_from_file;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler throws C2440 error and the error message is `'initializing': cannot convert from 'int *' to 'const T (*const )'`. It refers to %includePath%\boost\serialization\unique_ptr.hpp

```cpp
template<class Archive, class T>
inline void save(
    Archive & ar,
    const std::unique_ptr< T > &t,
    const unsigned int /*file_version*/
){
    // only the raw pointer has to be saved
    // the ref count is rebuilt automatically on load
    const T * const tx = t.get();
    ar << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(tx);
}
```

It seems that std::unique_ptr still serialize  unsuccessfully in boost-serialization library (version 1.72.0)?
Moreover, is there any solution to serialize a class with std::unique_ptr members?

Comment: @rafix07 Thank you for prompt reply and suggestion. I have ever consider the solution you mentioned that creating a vector for boost::serialization. However, I wonder that it may cause low efficiency in iterating over all items when `size` is large.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you just need to include `<boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>`?

Comment: @Quentin `#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>` and `#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>` also be needed for reading/writing class instance to archive in main.

Comment: @JimmyHu in addition to what you already have, I mean.

Comment: @Quentin I include the header files which maybe be used in serializing. In this case it should be fine in compiling and linking.

Comment: Lookig closer, you've been bitten by the most vexing parse: `A load_from_file();` declares a function, you want `A load_from_file;`. Even then, it seems like Boost.Serialization does not handle `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` correctly, because its `get()` function returns `T*` instead of `T (*)[]`.

Comment: @Quentin yes, thank you for detailed check. I already modified the question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that [std::unique_ptr doesn't stored size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662348/how-to-get-array-size-stored-in-unique-ptr), `ar& data;` in the "serialize" template function which is used for saving/loading data members *can't* be serialized due to the count of data is unknown in this line.

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar& data;        //    <==    the count of data is unknown 
    ar& size;
}
```

The iterating process (as shown as the following code) of smart pointer "data" is needed in order to access all valid data.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        ar& data[i];
```

Therefore, the save part is like below.

```
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const
{
    ar& size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        ar& data[i];
}
```

When it comes to load part, it is important to allocate space of smart pointer before loading data to avoid Access Violation Error

```
template<class Archive>
void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar& size;
    data = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);    //    <==    allocate space of smart pointer first
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        ar& data[i];
}
```

*Note:* The macro BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER() need to be put because save/load function is split.

Finally, the serialization part in class A could be done as the following code.

```
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const
{
    ar& size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        ar& data[i];
}
template<class Archive>
void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar& size;
    data = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        ar& data[i];
}
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
```

Reference: [Boost serialization tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the version of Boost you are using, you may need to implement your own non-intrusive adapter, something like this:

```
namespace boost { 
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive, class T>
inline void save( Archive & ar, const std::unique_ptr< T > &t, const unsigned int /*file_version*/){
    // only the raw pointer has to be saved
    const T * const base_pointer = t.get();
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(base_pointer);
}

template<class Archive, class T>
inline void load(Archive & ar,std::unique_ptr< T > &t, const unsigned int /*file_version*/){
    T *base_pointer;
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(base_pointer);
    t.reset(base_pointer);
}

template<class Archive, class T>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar,std::unique_ptr< T > &t, const unsigned int file_version){
    boost::serialization::split_free(ar, t, file_version);
}

} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12924315/4297146) for a complete example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The header file "unique_ptr.hpp" in boost library already included the template function "save", "load" and "serialize".